# Kali 2.0 screen freezing

Tags: drivers, kali-linux, graphics, freeze

Every time when I try to power off or reboot my laptop the screen freezes and I have to force power off, because the is the only option left.

From my experience I know that installing Nvidia card drivers should solve the problem, but I am unable to install drivers because the screen freezes during the installation at the moment when I need to shut down the X server either by typing init 3 or service gdm3 stop.

Does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: I don't have a solution to your question as it is too wide. But for debugging (read: reinstalling the necessary drivers), [single user mode](https://serverfault.com/questions/482079/debian-boot-to-single-user-mode) should be helpful.